# Is anybody know any free round button for development in Windows-mobile?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile

Is anybody know any free round button for development in Windows-mobile ?

thank's in advance

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense...

Comment: He's probably asking for a button control that is either circular or has rounded corners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is complete sample code for round buttons:

http://j2i.net/BlogEngine/post/2009/08/11/A-Good-Way-to-Render-Round-Buttons.aspx