# Windows CE UI Componets

Tags: windows-ce

Are there any UI Components for Windows CE 6.0, other than the ones supplied by the Compact Framework and Visual Studio? I am developing applications with C# and the Compact Framework that need some visual design and the VS controls and components are not sufficient to me.

Thx your answers.

Comment: Are you talking about components that are missing from your OS image? Or are you saying that the UI components in the toolbox in VS20XX are not sufficient to you?

Comment: Shaihi,
yes UI components in the toolbox in VS20XX are not sufficient to me.

Comment: Please be more precise with the terminology that you use. There are both **components** and **controls** in the framework and they are different. What you see is mostly (but not always) a **control**. A **component** mostly (but not always) exposes some non-UI functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this similar question: [Round buttons for Windows Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960662/is-anybody-know-any-free-round-button-for-development-in-windows-mobile). It should be relevant for Windows CE 6 as well. The example is in native code, but you can use SDF 1.4 source code to convert it to C#. I guess you can use the technique shown to create more controls of your own.

I also found this [article about creating custom controls](http://dvanderboom.wordpress.com/2008/03/14/compact-framework-creating-custom-controls-and-designers-part-1/) for Windows Mobile that might suite Windows CE as well as it is based on the compact framework, but I have not read this through nor tested it.

What components exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Thank you so much Shaihi,Components about buttons,lists,menus etc. similar to windows application components.

Comment: @jadeWarlord: Please be more precise with the terminology that you use. There are both **components** and **controls** in the framework and they are different. What you see is mostly (but not always) a **control**. A **component** mostly (but not always) exposes some non-UI functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Windows CE6 R3 now supports Silverlight, so you can do some pretty cool things, although i think it's a little more complicated than typical Silverlight.
http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/products/windowsce/silverlightforwe.mspx

Comment: Doobi thx your answer,
But our device not supported silverlight applications,It coast very high.

Comment: What costs too much? the license to include Silverlight in the image?

Comment: Look at the bottom of this link to see what components each license plan includes: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/products/windowsce/component-library.mspx
If you already have components from the `pro` license, then you can ask your OEM to include Silverlight in the image and it won't cost you more. It is an easy task for him to add Silverlight without adding hardware acceleration support. He just needs to add a catalog component.

Comment: Embedded Silverlight development is done in native language by the way **not** C#